# Android ListView not cleared even after deleting all items

Tags: android, android-listview

**UPDATE** : I am able to replicate this issue every time on my Galaxy S2 (with and without debugging mode), but never on the Emulator!

I am using a context menu on a `ListView` (which uses a custom implementation of `CursorAdapter`) to let the user select the option to '*Delete all*'. When this option is selected, all the items displayed in the list are supposed to get deleted permanently from the database, followed by a call to `changeCursor(..)` on the adapter to force the list to get updated.

What is happening, however, is that even after deleting the records from the database and calling `changeCursor(..)`, the items are visible. Only the item dividers disappear. Only after I touch somewhere on the list, do these items get cleared.

When the user activates the context menu :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivFvJ.png

After deletion from database AND calling `changeCursor(..)` : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX6BM.png

I am having another problem with ListView ([Android ListView items overlap while scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745599/android-listview-items-overlap-while-scrolling)), and I am using the same ListView, so maybe the problems are related? Is there some step to force the `ListView` to redraw after a database update? Or is it not happening automatically due to a mistake in how I've implemented the solution? Thanks in advance!

Here's the XML for the `ListView`

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/all_reminders_list"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:dividerHeight="1.0sp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
```

Here's the `newView(..)` method of my custom `CursorAdapter`

```
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_list_item, parent, false);
    return view;
}
```

The `bindView(..)` method of my `CursorAdapter`

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        TextView whatTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_what_text);
        whatTextView.setText(cursor.getString(1));
        TextView whenTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_when_text);


        if(cursor.getInt(9) != 0) // DONE_FLAG = 1 (completed)
        {
            //Arrow visibility
            ImageView arrow = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_arrow);
            arrow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            //Text color
            whatTextView.setTextColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            whenTextView.setTextColor(Color.LTGRAY);

            //WHEN text
            whenTextView.setText(TimeCalculationHelper.getCompletedTimeString(cursor.getLong(2)));
        }
        else // DONE_FLAG = 0
        {
            //Arrow visibility
            ImageView arrow = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_arrow);
            arrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //Text color
            whatTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            whenTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

            //WHEN text
            whenTextView.setText(TimeCalculationHelper.getTimeRemainingString(cursor.getLong(2)));


        }
}
```

Here's my `onContextItemSelected(..)` method from the `Activity` that contains the `ListView`

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        ListView allRemindersList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.all_reminders_list);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.delete_item:
            //Delete the selected reminder from the database
            databaseHelper.deleteRowByID(info.id);

            //Refresh the main activity list
            ((ActiveRemindersAdapter) allRemindersList.getAdapter()).changeCursor(databaseHelper.getAllRemindersForList());
            return true;

        case R.id.delete_done:
            //Delete all reminders with DONE_FLAG = 1
            databaseHelper.deleteDoneReminders();

            //Refresh the main activity list
            ((ActiveRemindersAdapter) allRemindersList.getAdapter()).changeCursor(databaseHelper.getAllRemindersForList());
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Try add `((ActiveRemindersAdapter) allRemindersList.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged()` call after you changed cursor.

Comment: Nikita is right, and better use a CursorAdapter from support library and call swapCursor() instead of changeCursor()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250770/how-to-refresh-android-listview

Comment: @SaifuddinSarker, I tried `invalidateViews()` too, but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Call **notifyDataSetChanged()** on your adapter after the cursor change to reload the views.
And better use a [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/CursorAdapter.html) from [SupportLibrary](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) if running pre-honeycomb devices.

Just looked into the code. Better use **swapCursor()** which automatically registers new content observers and calls **notifyDataSetChanged()** for you.

From CursorAdapter source code.

```
/**
 * Change the underlying cursor to a new cursor. If there is an existing cursor it will be
 * closed.
 * 
 * @param cursor The new cursor to be used
 */
public void changeCursor(Cursor cursor) {
    Cursor old = swapCursor(cursor);
    if (old != null) {
        old.close();
    }
}

/**
 * Swap in a new Cursor, returning the old Cursor.  Unlike
 * {@link #changeCursor(Cursor)}, the returned old Cursor is <em>not</em>
 * closed.
 *
 * @param newCursor The new cursor to be used.
 * @return Returns the previously set Cursor, or null if there wasa not one.
 * If the given new Cursor is the same instance is the previously set
 * Cursor, null is also returned.
 */
public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor newCursor) {
    if (newCursor == mCursor) {
        return null;
    }
    Cursor oldCursor = mCursor;
    if (oldCursor != null) {
        if (mChangeObserver != null) oldCursor.unregisterContentObserver(mChangeObserver);
        if (mDataSetObserver != null) oldCursor.unregisterDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
    }
    mCursor = newCursor;
    if (newCursor != null) {
        if (mChangeObserver != null) newCursor.registerContentObserver(mChangeObserver);
        if (mDataSetObserver != null) newCursor.registerDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
        mRowIDColumn = newCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id");
        mDataValid = true;
        // notify the observers about the new cursor
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        mRowIDColumn = -1;
        mDataValid = false;
        // notify the observers about the lack of a data set
        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    }
    return oldCursor;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Does `notifyDataSetChanged()` behave any differently from a call to `changeCursor()`? Will check and confirm if it solves my problem.
And I am only targetting ICS and newer devices.

Comment: Updated answer. notifyDataSetChanged() is a method of BaseAdapter (from which the CursorAdapter is extended) that forces reloading the views.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` after `changeCursor()`. I also tried calling `swapCursor()` instead. I still have the exactly same problem.

Comment: @PritinTyagaraj Do you perform a query after deletion before you change the Cursor? Are you sure the Cursor you set is empty? Log out cursor.getCount() and see how many rows in contains.

Comment: Yes, I have ensured the same. The `databaseHelper.getAllRemindersForList()` method actually performs a `SELECT` query and returns a `Cursor` for the result. Another strange thing I've noticed, that I am not able to replicate this in the Emulator, but I am able to replicate it every time on my Galaxy S2 (with and without being in debugging mode)

Comment: Did you try cursor.getCount()? Is et empty or not? If not - then it's now the ListView problem, but DB problem.

Comment: Apologies if my question wasn't clear (I'm not allowed to post more than 2 images). Please compare the first screenshot (before deletion - `ListView` has dividers) and the second screenshot (after deletion and `notifyDataSetChange()` - only dividers vanish). After deletion, once I touch anywhere on the list, the deleted items are removed from the screen. It is certainly a `ListView` UI rendering-related issue.

Comment: @PritinTyagaraj I remember some strange rendering with tabs on that device. Try adding android:background="#ffffffff" to your ListView. And after swapping Cursor call invalidate() on ListView.